# Save filter data in session using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, php-5.3, symfony-2.3

I have a question for you. I have a filter in the page that sort products by price. If I filter the products and for example I have 3 pages that when I switch to the page 2 the filter dissapear. I need to save this data in session? or exist another solution?
My controller :

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
        $aFilter['iMinPrice'] = $form["min_price"]->getData();
        $aFilter['iMaxPrice'] = $form["max_price"]->getData();
    }
    //Search products
    $aProducts          = $repositoryProduct->getProductsOrderByDateDesc($id,null,$aFilter);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $aProducts,
        $page,
        3
    );

    //Send data to view
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:category.html.twig',array(
        'category'          => $category,
        'pagination'        => $pagination,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

My repository :

```
if(!empty($aFilter)){
        if(isset($aFilter['iMinPrice'])){
            $qb->andWhere('p.product_price >= :price_min')
                ->setParameter('price_min',$aFilter['iMinPrice']);
        }
        if(isset($aFilter['iMaxPrice'])){
            $qb->andWhere('p.product_price <= :price_max')
                ->setParameter('price_max',$aFilter['iMaxPrice']);
        }
    }
```

And my view :

```
<form action="{{ path('show_product_category',{ 'id':category.getId(), 'name':category.getCategoryLink() }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
<div class="accordion-inner">
     {{ form_widget(form.min_price) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.max_price) }}
</div>
</form>
{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination, null, {}, {'style': 'pager', 'prev_label': '← Older', 'next_label': 'Newer →'}) }}
```

My route :

```
show_product_category:
path:     /{id}/{name}/{page}
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:Category:showCategory, page: 1}
requirements:
    id:  \d+
    page: \d+
    _method:  GET|POST
```

Help me please! Thx in advance!!! Any suggestions please how to append query parameters to the link?

Comment: Can't you use append a query string in your url where you can get the filter for your page? so if you switch to page 2 you'll just append it and use the Input `GET` by symfony.

Comment: I edited the question by adding my route and my form

Comment: If I change in the form method GET the url is like this: 
         ?product[min_price]=0&product[max_price]=30
If a switch to the page 2 the url is : /2 .

Comment: how do u switch to page 2? is it a menu or link? if it's like that you should have append the query parameters in the view... or if it's thru typing in the URL browser bar then it should be session

Comment: I edited the question, I switch to the page 2 using knp_paginator

Comment: is your page 2 another controller or the same controller? or specifically you only change the id when switching? does the link to page 2 rendered by the knp_paginator? because I think the knp_paginator only controlls the next /previous or specific pagination not the link to different ids.

Comment: I added the render of view....There is the same controller

Comment: your problem is your going to another page which makes the form invalid because you haven't use your form, the `$aFilter` will be null. I assume your form action is `GET`? you can use another if statement that if your url has a specific parameter, you'll assign it in the `$aFilter` variable

Answer (score 0):

You could try to append all GET parameters to all link of the pagination.
In this way, you'll have them everytime you switch page.

With KPNPaginator, you could pass your request query to the pagination renderer, like this:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination, null, _requestQuery, {'style': 'pager', 'prev_label': '← Older', 'next_label': 'Newer →'}) }}
```

In fact, KPN documentation states:

> By default when render method is triggered, pagination renders the
>   template with standard arguments provided:
>
> - `pagination parameters`, like pages in range, current page and so on..
> - `route` - which is used to generate page, sorting urls
> - `request_query`, which contains all GET request parameters
> - `extra`, pagination template parameters
>
> Except from pagination parameters, others can be modified
>   or adapted to some use cases. Usually its possible, you might need
>   setting a route if default is not matched correctly (because of
>   rendering in sub requests). Or adding additional query or view
>   parameters.

Comment: What do you mean? Was my answer helpful? If so, could you accept it, please?